# Wordpress WP_Query not returning post_type

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a 'featured content' section on my WordPress site homepage.
I've added a function to allow tags to be added to pages.

Then, in `index.php` I have added:

```
<?php $featured_pages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'tag' => 'featured', 
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));
if ( $featured_pages-> have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $featured_pages->have_posts() ) : $featured_pages-> the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-featured');
    endwhile; 
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But for some reason, the `post_type` part of the `WP_Query` array isn't working.
It returns all post_types.  If I change it to `'attachment'` it still returns posts and pages.

I'm new to WordPress, am I missing something here?

---

After further investigation it seems that the 'tag' overrides the 'post_type'.  Without that, it only shows pages.  With it, posts get included too.

Answer (score 0):

This question was unanswerable because I hadn't realised that the problem was caused by a function I'd added elsewhere that I didn't include here.

However, other people *may* find this useful as the code I used was largely taken from this resource https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-pages-use-tags.

I had added this function (copy and pasted from elsewhere):

```
function tags_support_query($wp_query) {
    if ($wp_query->get('tag')) $wp_query->set('post_type', 'any');
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'tags_support_query');
```

Which I think means, if you use `WP_Query` to get 'tag', it'll always set the post type to 'any'.  Which I guess isn't good, so I deleted it and my code in the question works as expected.